# Android Bluetooth Error: Socket failed (GPS iTag and android app)

Tags: android, bluetooth, gps, android-bluetooth

I want to connect my GPS iTag Tracker to my app via Bluetooth and get the location from that.
How do I do it? I am getting this error. What are the possible ways I could go wrong?
How do I connect my GPS iTag Tracker to my app?

```
java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
                                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readAll(BluetoothSocket.java:1054)
                                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.readInt(BluetoothSocket.java:1068)
                                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:583)
```

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Just tell me whether I must use `createRfCommSocketToServiceRecord` or `listenUsingRfCommSocketToServiceRecord`. Also, please tell me how I can get the UUID from the GPS Itag Tracker. `adapter.getBondedDevices().uuids` is a null array it seems.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.